# HTML in a Vuetify v-dialog

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to add formatted HTML to the inside of a v-dialog.  I had a v-card inside but I have ripped that out so I can start from scratch.  This is what I have so far

```
       <v-dialog v-model="dialogPubs" scrollable max-width="950px">      
       <div>{{editedItem.Publication}}</div>
       </v-dialog>
```

The {{editedItem.Publication}} contains formatted HTML with color changes and also hyperlinks.  I've seen where using the v-card the v-text with v-html is suppose to work but it didn't for me.

I have a data-table where when I double click on a row the dialog pops up with the formatted HTML but I'm getting straight text.  If I need to put the v-card back that is fine as long as I can render HTML.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please double check how you are using `v-html`.  You need to use it on the element that will contain HTML and you need to add it as an attribute that binds to a `data` property containing an HTML string.  Please see below.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      show: true,
      stuff: "<span><strong>hello</strong> <span>world</span></span>"
    };
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@3.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-layout>
        <v-dialog v-model="show" scrollable max-width="950px">
          <v-card>
            <div v-html="stuff"></div>
          </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
      </v-layout>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked.  Thanks.  I was trying to wrap the v-html around the {{ editedItem.Publication }}  Setting it up your way worked.  Thanks again

Comment: how about this situation?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57317384/dynamically-build-a-html-color-enhanced-list-using-vueitify I'm sure it can use your insight